# Star Wars and the body snatchers: Running nightwatch tests on linux box

Tags: linux, selenium, nightwatch.js

I am trying to run nightwatch automated UI tests on a linux box (centos OS). I have the following nightwatch.json configuration:

```
{
    "src_folders": [
        "tests"
    ],
    "output_folder": "reports",
    "custom_commands_path": "custom_commands",
    "custom_assertions_path": "",
    "page_objects_path": "",
    "live_output" : true,
    "globals_path": "globals.js",
    "selenium": {
        "start_process": true,
        "server_path": "lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar",
        "log_path": "",
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": 4444,
        "cli_args": {
            "webdriver.chrome.driver": "lib/chromedriver",
            "webdriver.chromeJenkins.driver": "../../tools/chromedriver/chromedriver",
            "webdriver.ie.driver": "lib/IEDriverServer_x64_2.52.2.exe",
            "trustAllSSLCertificates": true
        }
    },
    "test_workers": {
        "enabled": true,
        "workers": "auto"
    },
    "test_settings": {
        "default": {
            "launch_url": "",
            "selenium_port": 4444,
            "selenium_host": "localhost",
            "silent": true,
            "screenshots": {
                "enabled": true,
                "on_failure": true,
                "on_error": true,
                "path": "./screenshots"
            },
            "end_session_on_fail": false,
            "desiredCapabilities": {
                "browserName": "chrome",
                "javascriptEnabled": true,
                "acceptSslCerts": true,
                "chromeOptions": {
                    "args": [
                        "use-fake-device-for-media-stream",
                        "use-fake-ui-for-media-stream"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
      "jenkins" : {
            "selenium_port"  : 4444,
            "selenium_host"  : "127.0.0.1",
            "cli_args" : {
                "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "lib/chromedriver"
        },
        "chromeOptions" : {
             "args" : ["--no-sandbox"]
        },
            "desiredCapabilities": {
                "browserName": "chrome",
                "javascriptEnabled": true,
                "acceptSslCerts": true,
                "platform" : "LINUX",
            "chromeOptions" : {
                "args" : ["--no-sandbox"]
            } 
            }
    }
}
```

I am using the jenkins environment.

I installed chromedriver to lib/ folder
I installed the selenium-standalone.jar to lib/ folder

But when I run the tests by doing node nightwatch --test tests/login.js

I get the error:

```
Error retrieving a new session from the selenium server


Connection refused! Is selenium server started?
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's very likely your server_path. I've run into this issue when installing Nightwatch before and end up searching the subdirectories in node_modules in order to find the selenium-server-standalone jar. At times I've even had to just install it separately.  Currently I have it as "server_path": "./node_modules/testarmada-magellan-nightwatch/node_modules/selenium-server/lib/runner/selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar", though you are very likely to find it elsewhere.